# Criptografia de uma classe em C#

Tags: php, c#, criptografia

Tenho o seguinte código em PHP:

```
    $params = json_decode(trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $api_secret, base64_decode($enc_request), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
```

Onde o resultado é um array e não uma string.

Os meus dados que preciso enviar são esses:

```
Dados dados = new Dados ();

dados.Controller = "Get";
dados.Action = "FindIdUsuario_get";
dados.Email = "contato@rafaellincoln.com";
dados.Pass = "teste";
```

Como faço pra criptografar esses classe usando Rijndael para enviar na minha url?

**UPDATE**

Segue o código da criptografia que uso em php:

```
$request_params = array();
$request_params['controller'] = 'Get';
$request_params['action'] = 'FindIdUsuario_get';
$request_params['email'] = 'contato@rafaellincoln.com';
$request_params['pass'] = 'teste';
echo base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $public_key, json_encode($request_params), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567056/rijndael-encryption-decryption-c-sharp-vs-php

Comment: Eu não quero criptografar uma string, e sim um classe.

Comment: não vai rolar isso que vc quer fazer.

Comment: Resposta curta: serialize o objeto em JSON, encripte, do outro lado decripte e de-serialize o JSON de volta num objeto. Porém: a) por que passar via GET, e não via POST? b) por que não usar SSL/TLS em vez de uma criptografia "feita à mão"? c) os dois lados da comunicação possuem a chave secreta? d) **NUNCA** USE O MODO ECB NA PRÁTICA!!! Use um modo mais seguro, como CBC ou CTR, ou melhor ainda um autenticado, como OCB/CCM/GCM/EAX.

Comment: P.S. Se o código em PHP não puder ser modificado por algum motivo (por exemplo, se ele for de terceiros) e tudo o que você precisa é criar um código C# "compatível", por favor edite sua pergunta dando um exemplo de resultado esperado, aí talvez possamos te ajudar melhor (mas fica ainda a ressalva de que usar ECB não é seguro na prática, em particular se você enviar o mesmo bloco mais de uma vez).

Comment: O que é esse `$public_key`? O AES/Rijndael é um algoritmo de criptografia **simétrica**, de modo que a mesma chave é usada pra cifrar e pra decifrar. Por acaso essa variável é a mesma coisa que `$api_secret`?

Comment: E a mesma sim. Eu só quero saber como fazer a criptografia de um array em c# da mesma forma que faço em PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Classes são conjuntos de dados. Basicamente (e totalmente a grosso modo) é uma estrutura. Você até poderia manipular em baixo nível e criptografar essa classe, mas a partir deste feito, o VM não reconhecerá mais esta classe e eliminará ela da memória.

Se deseja ocultar TODOS os dados dessa classe, tem que aplicar criptografia a cada campo do mesmo, já que por baixo dos panos estes dados estarão sequenciais e não existirá essa divisão bonita e legível que vemos na hora de programar, deixando a "Classe" totalmente criptografada.

Para enviar este mesmo por uma URL, basta tu organizar em uma string maior, criptografar esta string e passar. Outro método MUITO MELHOR é por Post (form).